# Source code for bypass list in chrome.proxy

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Chrome and Firefox have slightly different implementation for the proxy [bypassList](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/proxy/#bypass-list).

Where is the source code for the `bypassList` implementation in chrome?

I need to convert it to Vanilla JavaScript (if not already), in order to manually implement it where needed e.g. in PacScript.

Is there a Vanilla JavaScript version of it?